# Cannot get facebook user feed using javascript

Tags: facebook

I need to get the user facebook feed and I have two account. Account A can get the feed detail. However account B cannot. Why this happened? It is related to the user facebook setting?I use the following FB api

```
var url = '/me/feed?fields=place,created_time';
FB.api(url, function (response) {
console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that:

1. Your app is live and the relevant permissions are approved by facebook
2. or if your app is not live yet, all users are listed as admin/developer/tester under the App Roles **AND** have the proper permissions (e.g. [`user_posts`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed))